# How to update with CRUD system in RAILS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

I'm learning Rails and I'm trying to use CRUD system.
I want to update my article when I click on the "Edit" button.
Problem, I get this error **"ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/articles/1/edit"):"**

I used "resources :articles" to create all routes for CRUD system in my routes.rb file.

Here my routes :

```
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)  articles#edit                                                       

             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)       articles#update                                                             

             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)       articles#update
```

Here is my form :

```
<%= form_with do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Titre de l'article</label>
    <%= text_field :title, '', class:'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Contenu de l'article</label>
    <%= text_area :content, '', class:'form-control'%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier l'article</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I think it's related to the HTTP protocol of the update action which is in PATCH/PUT when we use :resource.

Link to documentation I used for doing this : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form_with` will replace `form_tag` and `form_for` that will be depreciated in the future, because it combines these two helpers.

In your form, you forgotten your object, so the form is not able to know what should be updated.

Replacing `form_with do` by `form_with model: @article do` should do the trick

```
<%= form_with model: @article do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Titre de l'article</label>
    <%= text_field :title, '', class:'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Contenu de l'article</label>
    <%= text_area :content, '', class:'form-control'%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier l'article</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this you need to give controller action through form submit

```
<%= form_for @artice, url: {action: :update} do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Titre de l'article</label>
    <%= text_field :title, '', class:'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Contenu de l'article</label>
     <%= text_area :content, '', class:'form-control'%>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier l'article</button>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It worked well ! I thought the form_for was no longer used! And I thought that form_with automagically retrieved the action for my submit ^^". Not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_with model: @article do |t| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Titre de l'article</label>
    <%= t.text_field :title, class:'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Contenu de l'article</label>
    <%= t.text_area :content, class:'form-control'%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= t.submit "Modifier l'article", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: OK, nice, it worked Except I have a "redirect_to article_path" in my update action that no longer works when I use form_with

Comment: Try to replace it with ``redirect_to @article``